# Tkinter frame has dimensions different from dimensions given to and idk why

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, dimensions

I'm struggling with Tkinter now. I wanted to create layout but if I define window dimensions (800x600) and create frame which have to be wide 800 too, it have just half.

I tried googling and changing code, if I multiply width 2 times (to 1600) then frame fit the screen perfetly.

Here is code:

```
import tkinter as tk

SW, SH = 800, 600

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry(f"{SW}x{SH}")

frm_appname = tk.Frame(
    master = win,
    bg = 'red'
)

frm_appname.place(
    anchor = tk.N,
    width = 800,
    relheight = (1/6)
)
```

Here is output:
[image]

Can anyone explain me what happened here?

Comment: While I do not know the exact mechanism behind the place method I can tell you that by removing the `anchor` or set it to `tk.NW` the code does what it should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor of "n" (tk.N) means that the top *center* portion of the frame is at the given coordinate. Since you didn't provide an x and y coordinate for `place` it defaults to 0,0. So, the top/middle (400,0) of the frame is at coordinate 0,0.

If you set the anchor to "n" or `tk.NW`, the top-left corner of your frame will be in the top-left corner of the window.

---

On an unrelated note, experience has taught me that layouts are nearly always easier to create with `pack` and/or `grid`. In my coupe of decades of using tk and tkinter, I've never used `place` for more than one or two special-case widgets.